# Wordpress variables

Tags: wordpress, variables, content-management-system

In my Wordpress page I have on many pages repeating info, Like: "this year we have sold **1000** cars"  and I wanna update the number from one place for all pages. 
How should I do it? Some plugin? Thanks

Comment: If you are using widget for that info. then you can easily update that info. from one place. For this type of fix info. please create  widget so in future easily you can update from one widget.

Comment: No, I'm not using any widgets. I just did it by PHP, but for some people isn't it good way how to do it. So if you can recommend me some WP plugin or way how to do it right in WP let me know. Thanks

Comment: You have only way to create widget for that text.so in future you need to change in widget only and it will change in whole site.

Answer (score 1):

The circumstances thus need a custom widget area. In order to create a custom widget area do the following.

Add the following code to your `functions.php`

```
// Custom widget area.
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Custom Widget Area'),
    'id' => 'custom-widget-area',
    'description' => __( 'An optional custom widget area for your site', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Add the below code to where you want the widget get displayed.

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'Custom Widget Area' );
```

This will solve your problem.

Do not forget to add text widget to the Custom Widget Area in Menu > Appearance > Widgets.

Comment: I dont have there **Primary Slidebar** but **Primary widget area**. I have added there **Text widget**. Then I used `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` to call it but I dont see anything.

Comment: Or else try <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?> instead <?php get_sidebar(); ?>. You can also try sidebar-2 or sidebar-3 as it will be different for different themes.

Comment: Can u mention ur theme name and WordPress version?

Comment: WordPress 4.0.1 and its Custom theme

Comment: Thank you for the code. I believe there has to be better way. If not I can use my good old PHP code :)

Comment: Now I just installed **Just Variables** and used its code `<?php just_variable( "code for variable" ); ?>` but it not working.